# asp.net core 5.0 RequestSizeLimit not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-5

I am using ASP.net core 5.0 and it seems `RequestSizeLimit` is not working.

I have the following controller

```
[HttpPost("addfile")]
[RequestSizeLimit(5_242_880)] // 5MB
public IActionResult AddFile([FromBody] IFormFile file)
```

Now when I want to test said controller, I create an `IFormFile` like this:

```
public static Mock<IFormFile> TestFile(string filename, string content)
{
    var fileMock = new Mock<IFormFile>();

    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    var writer = new StreamWriter(ms);
    writer.Write(content);
    writer.Flush();
    ms.Position = 0;
    fileMock.Setup(_ => _.OpenReadStream()).Returns(ms);
    fileMock.Setup(_ => _.FileName).Returns(filename);
    fileMock.Setup(_ => _.Length).Returns(ms.Length);

    return fileMock;
}
```

In my test I now add 50MB of content like this:

```
var bigContent = RandomString(50 * 1024 * 1024);
var testFile = TestFile("calendar.ical", bigContent);
...
var result = controller.AddFile(testFile.Object);
```

Info: `RandomString` returns a string for a given length (not the most optimized way):

```
public static string RandomString(int length)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    Random random = new Random();
    char ch;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        ch = Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(26 * random.NextDouble() + 65)));
        builder.Append(ch);
    }
    return builder.ToString();
}
```

I would expect an status code that is not 200 - OK.
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: This seems like a config error with the webserver, https://khalidabuhakmeh.com/increase-file-upload-limit-for-aspdotnet might help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are unit testing the controller - unfortunately the `[RequestSizeLimit]` attribute is implemented as a filter in the request pipeline - and filters are not run as part of unit tests.

This is described [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/testing?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

> Set up unit tests of controller actions to focus on the controller's behavior. A controller unit test avoids scenarios such as filters, routing, and model binding. Tests that cover the interactions among components that collectively respond to a request are handled by integration tests. For more information on integration tests, see Integration tests in ASP.NET Core.

More information on Integration Tests can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Comment: Oh, I did not know that. Thank you very much for this answer.