# Why does RequestSizeLimitAttribute not work on my WebApiController action?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

In .NET 6, I have a controller like

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/myfiles")]
public class MyFileController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost()]
    [Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
    [RequestSizeLimit(1024)]
    public async Task<ActionResult<MyFile>> SaveMyFile(Myfile file) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I then have integration tests running on this. The authorize attribute works, the post attribute of course works. I've got all my tests passing except the one related to the `RequestSizeLimit` attribute. I put a breakpoint in the SaveMyFile function and I can receive objects even if they have a byte array of random numbers that are way larger than whatever I put in the RequestSizeLimit. What am I missing?

Comment: Hope this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65587598/asp-net-core-5-0-requestsizelimit-not-working) can give you some help.

Comment: Sorry, @XinranShen, it does not. That is referring to a user doing unit tests. My post says I'm doing integration tests and my tests for other attributes are working.  I actually found this conversation explaining that it is a behavior specific to the ASP Test Server implementation. https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/13895 Optional features like IHttpMaxRequestBodySizeFeature which is used by RequestSizeLimit under the hood are not set by default for the test server. Now I'm trying to figure out how to add the feature to an my TestFactory used by XUnit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the underlying TestServer created for .NET 6 does not include lesser used "Features". These are actual classes and modules of the server that have been left out to make the tests faster from what I understand. To get around it, I effectively reimplemented it with a mock, but that feels like cheating.

Alternatives are just adding tests that verify the attribute exists on the endpoint or maybe doing a full test deployment in a CI build and running tests on that